# Cannot connect to wifi on login screen after update from 14.04 to 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04

I need to connect to wifi and then VPN before I login. I could do that in 14.04, but in 18.04 the option is greyed out. Is there a way to add permissions for no user to connect to wifi?